# Why does this limit equal 0?

Tags: limits, infinity

I'm trying to solve the limit:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^3+2^x}{x^2+3^x}$$ 
So far I've divided every term by $3^x$ and this is correct according to the solution, which gets me: $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{x^3}{3^x}+( \frac{2}{3})^x}{\frac{x^2}{3^x}+1}$$
I would've said that the $X^3/3^x$ goes to 0 and the $(2/3)^x$ goes to infinity and then $x^2/3^x$ goes to 0 and the one stays as it is. This would give $\frac{0+\infty}{0+1}$ which is the same as $\frac{\infty}{1}$ which is infinity.

However, the answer according to the solution is 0; could anyone explain why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Why would $(2/3)^x$ go to infinity?

Comment: $(2/3)^x$ goes to 0 not to infinity if x go to infinity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error lies here:

> I would've said that the $X^3/3^x$ goes to 0 and **the $(2/3)^x$ goes to infinity**

The asymptotic behaviour of the exponential function $a^x$ depends on the base $a$:

- if $a>1$, then $a^x$ is a strictly *increasing* function and $a^x \to +\infty$ for $x \to +\infty$;
- if $0<a<1$, then $a^x$ is a strictly *decreasing* function and $a^x \to 0$ for $x \to +\infty$.

In your case $\left(\tfrac{2}{3}\right)^x \to 0$ for $x \to +\infty$ because $0<\tfrac{2}{3}<1$.